# Matlab: Filter a timetable to balance a panel data

Tags: matlab, filter, extract, panel-data, timetable

I have a timetable and I want to keep those days that coincide between each value from my variable "Id". In the example I put here, I start with my timetable T where there are three different "Id". My goal would be to end up with a timetable T_1 where only the observations where the dates coincide between each "Id" are kept.

```
T= timetable(datetime({'13/04/2018';'25/04/2018';'28/04/2018';'13/04/2018';'25/04/2018';'13/04/2018'}), [1;1;1;2;2;3],[30;29;45;21;24;8] );
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'Id' 'Price'}

%I want to get:

T_1=timetable(datetime({'13/04/2018';'13/04/2018';'13/04/2018'}), [1;2;3],[30;21;8] );
```

I woudl be really thankful if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
T_1 = T('13/04/2018',:);
```

I would advice you to read the [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerange.html#d122e1343230) about `timerange` and timetables in general.

If you want to split the timetable in multiple smaller timetables, you can select them by date, and store them in a cell array:

```
T_unique = unique(T.Time); % get all unique dates
T_all = cell(size(T_unique)); % init an empty cell array
for k = 1:numel(T_unique)
    T_all{k} = T(T_unique(k),:); % and put the timetable for one date in the cell array
end
```

Comment: Thank you @rinkert, but this was just an example. In reality I have a big timetable (size 47000 * 11) so the main purpose is that Matlab identifies the dates that appear in all the "Id" and creates a new timetable with only those dates and variables linked with. It is impossible to do this date by date, as you suggested.

Comment: @AntoineFa I thought so, but then please state that in the question. See the update, this will work, but most likely you want to use some function like [`splitapply`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) to determine per date